# masked box asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I use masked edit box control in my application. When user
click masked edit box, cursor locate in middle of control
or end of control. users have to use cursor key to bring
cursor front of control. Is there any way I can set cursor
location in front of control when user click the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the `SelectionStart` Property for `MaskedTextBox`

```
private void maskedTextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    maskedTextBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
}
```